# JSF/Primefaces - Proper way to create a page for manipulating a collection<B> stored in an Entity A

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, datatable, entity

Table B has a foreign key to the table A.
Using JSF and Primefaces with NetBeans I have automagically generated Entities, Controllers, Facades and JSF Pages.
Entity A has a collection of Entity B.

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "idA")
private Collection<B> BCollection;
```

I need to realize a page with 2 datatables. Datatable A contains *all* the items from table A.

```
<p:dataTable id="datalist" widgetVar="datalist" value="#{AController.items}" var="item"
                             selectionMode="single" selection="#{AController.selected}"
                             paginator="true"
                             rowKey="#{item.id}"
                             rows="5"
                             rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10,15,20,25"
                             >
```

Datatable B must contain *all the B items related to the selected A item*.
I tried with:

```
<p:dataTable id="datalistMOC" widgetVar="datalistMOC" value="#{AController.selected.BCollection}" var="itemMOC"
                             selectionMode="single" selection="#{BController.selected}"
                             paginator="true"
                             rowKey="#{itemMOC.id}"
                             rows="5"
                             rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10,15,20,25"
                             >
```

But with this kind of solution every insert, delete and update operation on datatable B is reflected in the DB but not in the page.

Does exist a straightforward method to accomplish this behavior?

**EDIT**: why datatable A is updating automatically after a delete, insert or edit operation, while datatable B needs to be updated manually? Maybe I have to use BController to handle IT? What's missing?

Comment: I'm going to check it tomorrow. I'll per you know.

Comment: @BalusC Yes, managed beans are session scoped.

Comment: @BalusC I think scoping is not a problem, otherwise all the others datatable in my web application would not be updated after every insert, delete, or update operation.

Comment: @BalusC of course not! I'm sorry, but I can't understand how this is related to my problem.

Comment: Post a MCVE http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info There's too many ambiguity in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Every time you perform an insert, delete or update operation you should navigate back to the page using the post-get-redirect pattern. So at the end of your backing bean action method you should have a line similar to this:

```
return "/pageWithTablesAandB?faces-redirect=true";
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm not sure this is the "best" solution. Table A is auto updating, why can't I get the same result on Table B? I think my error is to access Collection<B> directly from A entity bean.

Comment: The way you are using for accesing to your B children entities seems correct. Keep in mind that when you delete a B entity, apart from performing the JPA remove operation, you have to update your model removing this element from the A father entity's BCollection property. Or you can refresh your entire model as I proposed you in my initial answer.

Comment: Thanks. Tomorrow I'll try your solution. Meanwhile I edited the question.